# build folder create under the android/app folder?

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-dependencies

When I am run the my flutter app,
**/android/app/** in this path automatically generate **build** folder & it contains some generated apk supported files & etc.

- /android/app/build/generated
- /android/app/build/intermediates
- /android/app/build/outputs
- /android/app/build/tmp

above list are the build folder paths

I didn't know where the issue occurs.
Is this normal matter.

Comment: No this is not normal. You can create another project and see.

Comment: when I am going to push the repo to the github , it will not contains in the .gitignore file, is that should I add those to gitignore

Comment: I think you should make it so that these folders are not created. Maybe delete /android/app/build folder and build again. Maybe it won't happen again.

Comment: okay I will try, Thank you for your reply

Comment: There is a also a related issue on GitHub: [android_intent_plus - Building app with plugin causes APK build output to be placed outside of <project dir>\build directory](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/282)

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, even worse, each run add new android folder inside build folder, and after some time I have to many nested folders [nestedfolders img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CQ5C.png)

I edit my android/build.gradle and change:

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

to:

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

that solve my problem :)

Problem starts after I add some dependencies, and update flutter to 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. By the way, does anyone know the root cause of this?